# How to select n row from table where there is 300'000 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to take every 4 rows from my table, but I have some error with my query.

Here is my table :

```
id | IfInOctets |  IfOutOctets | inDiff | outDiff |    time    | timeDiff
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 283994207  |  117876089   |  1716  |  52872  | 1555658221 |    59
2  | 283995596  |  117928892   |  1389  |  52803  | 1555658282 |    61
3  | 283995978  |  117929215   |  382   |  323    | 1555658341 |    59
4  | 283996278  |  117929407   |  300   |  192    | 1555658402 |    61
5  | 283996595  |  117929703   |  317   |  296    | 1555658461 |    59
6  | 283998848  |  117932946   |  2253  |  3243   | 1555658522 |    61
7  | 284001482  |  117935214   |  2634  |  2268   | 1555658581 |    59
8  | 284001824  |  117935472   |  342   |  258    | 1555658642 |    61
9  | 284004728  |  117939762   |  2904  |  4290   | 1555658701 |    59
```

My query is :

```
SELECT t.id, t.time
FROM
(
    SELECT id, `time`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `time`) AS rownum
    FROM monitor
) AS t
WHERE t.rownum % 25 = 0
ORDER BY t.time
```

The error :

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(ORDER BY `time`) AS rownum
>           FROM mytable
>       ) AS t
>       WHERE t.rownu' at line 4

You can try here :

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8074b4/3

Comment: what is your db version - it's working here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=24137c069feab814099e090c6f54c8b0

Comment: It looks like you're not running MySQL 8+...

Comment: Here is the version `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Comment: Version 5.5 doesn't support window functions.

Comment: @executable MySQL introduced the ROW_NUMBER() function since version 8.0.

Comment: Oh ok thank you to point it out, there is a way to do it in this version instead upgrading it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate the `ROW_NUMBER()` function using variables in MySQL prior to 8.0:

```
SELECT t.id, t.time
FROM (SELECT id, time, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum
      FROM monitor
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      ORDER BY time) t
WHERE t.rownum % 4 = 0
ORDER BY t.time
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
id  time
4   1555658402
8   1555658642
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cGkKnh2xu6HX3BH64LM9Ux/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where id in (select id from table where id%4=0)
```